# .zshrc:export:17: not valid in this context

Tags: macos, terminal, zshrc

I'm currently struggling with an error in terminal in Mac. Can someone help me to fix it?

I already tried some other forum solutions (using export and other similar solutions), but none of them was useful. 
Here's the error 
/Users/alessandromasala/.zshrc:export:17: not valid in this context: Preview.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

This is the content of my .zshrc

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/alessandromasala/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/alessandromasala/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/alessandromasala/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/alessandromasala/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/Users/alessandromasala/miniconda3/bin:/Users/alessandromasala/miniconda3/condabin:/Users/alessandromasala/.pyenv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion Tech Preview.app/Contents/Public:/Library/TeX/texbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
```

Comment: We can't help without seeing the `.zshrc` file....

Comment: Sorry I'm not really practical on this topic, I just added the screen of the content

Comment: [Please do not upload images of files/code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Now I added the code without images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on line 17 (the `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:...` command), the spaces in `VMware Fusion Tech Preview.app` need to be quoted or escaped. Actually, it looks to me like that command got prematurely expanded, since it's replacing the entire `PATH` value rather than just adding to it like normal (which means that, for example, it's replacing whatever changes the earlier conda setup part did).

I suspect that entire line should be replaced by:

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: The problem was that ```VMware Fusion Tech Preview.app``` was not quoted. Thank you very much for solving my problem